# BeautifulSoup webscraping images Flipkart url list not found

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have been trying to webscrape images from flipkart.com for the sunglasses Raybay. I haven't been able to extract urls of the images. The code is below:- Could anyone help me with the corrected code?

```
url=requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=raybay%20sunglasses%20for%20women&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off")
content=url.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
image_url = []
p=soup.find_all('img', {'class':'_3togXc'})
for item in p:
    imgdata=item.findChildren('alt src')
    for i in imgdata:
        image_url.append(i)
```

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: What *exactly* is your issue and your question?

Comment: Didn't you mean `Ray-Ban`? Oh, and the content of the website is behind JS, which means `BeautifulSoup` won't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that page content is rendered dynamically by javascript, so I would recommend combine BeautifulSoup with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

wd = webdriver.Chrome('<PATH_TO_SELENIUM_WEBDRIVER>', options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=raybay%20sunglasses%20for%20women&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off'

# load page via selenium
wd.get(url)

# wait 5 seconds until results table will be loaded
table = WebDriverWait(wd, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '_1HmYoV')))

# parse content of the grid
soup = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')

# extract image URLs
image_url = [image['src'] for image in soup.find_all('img', {'class':'_3togXc'})]
        
print(image_url)
```